# Getting form input using express then inserting to mysql database returns and inserts blank

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, express

(noob alert) Sup guys. I'm an extreme beginner and this will be my first question so I'd be grateful if someone could lend me a hand with this. I just started learning express today and I'm not sure yet where to put what but I'm pretty sure that's why this isn't working properly. It only returns message = "" and inserts a blank into the database instead of the message typed inside the textarea. Sorry for the noob question

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()
const mysql = require("mysql")
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "......",
    database: "chat_database"
})



app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")))
app.listen(3000)

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const data = req.body.message
    console.log(data);

    let sql = `INSERT INTO chats(content) VALUES (?)`
    connection.query(sql, [data], (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log(result);
        console.log("data has been successfully inserted into the database!");
    })
})



const mainChatBlock = document.querySelector("#main-chat-block")
const mainInputArea = document.querySelector("#main-input-area")
const mainSendButton = document.querySelector("#main-send-button")

mainSendButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let newMessage = document.createElement("div")
    newMessage.innerHTML = mainInputArea.value
    mainChatBlock.append(newMessage)
    mainInputArea.value = ""
    mainChatBlock.scrollTop = mainChatBlock.scrollHeight
})

mainInputArea.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    mainSendButton.click();
    }   
});
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>my chat</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
  <body>
    <main>
        <div id="outermost-main-div">
            <div id="outermost-chat-div">
                <div id="main-chat-area">
                    <div id="main-chat-block">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <form action="/" method="post" id="outer-input-area">
                    <textarea name="message" id="main-input-area" placeholder=">>> Enter your message here"></textarea>
                    <button type="submit" id="main-send-button">Send</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out guys. turns out the culprit was the clear value in the client side js  `mainInputArea.value = ""`
but to clear the entry, I did something like this

```js
mainSendButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let newMessage = document.createElement("div")
    newMessage.innerHTML = mainInputArea.value
    mainChatBlock.append(newMessage)
    mainChatBlock.scrollTop = mainChatBlock.scrollHeight
    setTimeout(del, 100)
})
function del() {
    mainInputArea.value = ""
}
```